# Firebase Cloud Function with Flask infinite loop accessing request.json

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a JSON API with Flask and the google cloud functions framework.
My problem appears when I try to access to the body of the request. I'm new with cloud functions, but it looks really strange. In the following code and console prints, it is evident that the flask endpoint function is returning a response, but the cloud function not.

```py
@app.route("/events",methods=['POST'])
def post_event():
    # new_event = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    new_event = request.json
    print(new_event)
    return {"message":"Event created successfully"}, 201

# Expose Flask app as a single Cloud Function:

@https_fn.on_request(max_instances=10)
def httpsflaskexample(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    with app.request_context(req.environ):
        flask_response = app.full_dispatch_request()
        print(flask_response)
        return flask_response
```

The console (the last print, is the `print(flask_response)` statement):

```
>  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
>   * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8374
>  Press CTRL+C to quit
>  <Response streamed [404 NOT FOUND]>
>  127.0.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2023 20:51:58] "GET /__/health HTTP/1.1" 404 -
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-httpsflaskexample"
>  {'name': 'Add your name in the body'}
>  <Response 41 bytes [201 CREATED]>

(*Infinite loop or something happen)
```

After a minutes the following error appears:

```
i  Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout, see
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
i  Request to function failed: Error: socket hang up
>  [2023-09-24 20:52:58,110] ERROR in app: Exception on /events [POST]
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
>      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1487, in full_dispatch_request
>      return self.finalize_request(rv)
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1508, in finalize_request
>      response = self.process_response(response)
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2002, in process_response
>      response = self.ensure_sync(func)(response)
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\functions_framework\__init__.py", line 302, in read_request
>      flask.request.get_data()
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\request.py", line 423, in get_data
>      rv = self.stream.read()
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 829, in readall
>      data = self.read(1024 * 64)
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 814, in readinto
>      self.on_disconnect()
>    File "...\functions\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 751, in on_disconnect
>      raise ClientDisconnected()
>  werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

I tried using `request.get_data(as_text=True)` instead of `request.json` as is indicated in the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd#python-preview_2), but it has the same problem.

Comment: `ERROR in app: Exception on /events [POST]` implies an exception was thrown by your code. It might be because `request` is not in scope and should be `flask.request`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when i tried to use request.get_data() or request.get_json() with flask in firebase, then will never get the response until 60s timeout...
So the issue is about Flask request and firebase_functions's request conflict.
You can save function:"httpsflaskexample"'s request as globle variable and use
in your route function...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).